# How should I hang a receptacle on a rim joist?

Tags: receptacle, gfci, safety, outdoor

So I am wiring my cabin, and here I have a crawlspace which I will button up with some mesh & skirting, but for all intents & purposes, I am considering it open to everything (dogs, rodents, armadillos, pterodactyls, you name it ... this is North Texas) ... But I need power outside, so I have two of these outlets to wire.

[image: cabin foundation]

They will be supplied by a 20A GFCI breaker just for these two 20A receptacles. I plan on putting PVC (or metal?) in-use boxes for them. Under the cabin I plan to run properly supported 1/2in grey PVC using the little t-boxes shown below where the wire splits out to the receptacles. Wire will be 12 GA THHN/THWN copper stranded hot,neutral and ground, and making wire-nut connections in the t-box.

[image: T-box]

The receptacles are the kind where you insert the wire and the clamps down on it. It's this one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-Commercial-Grade-Duplex-Outlet-White-R62-CBR20-00W/202066702

[image: 20A outlet]

So, I like the first method, where the box sort of "hangs" from the rim joist, except of course I'll have it backed by a 2x6 screwed to the inside of the rim joist and hanging down. In this way I imagine I can get a cleaner install by drilling though the back of the board, and joining up the PVC to the center of the back of the box.

- Is there a better way?
- Have I thought this out correctly?
- Am I being too cautious with the PVC, when just UF (or heck even romex) will do?
- Should I also use a combo AFCI/GFCI? Seems like GFCI-only is the
  right choice here.

You guys have been really terrific with the advice, which I appreciate in advance!

--Kerry

Comment: Can you use a GFCI or DFCI breaker?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel ... I am planning on using just the GFCI breaker. I suppose I could use a combo breaker, but would that be overkill? GFCI is really for shocks, and AFCI for sparks & fires, right? But I guess wires could come loose and spark/arc/etc inside those boxes, huh. What do you think?

Comment: use the screws on the side for secure connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were doing this I would use Carlon Type FS boxes and rigid NM conduit. These boxes can be fitted with water-tight covers and have screws for surface mount to the existing rim joist. I would run conduit under the joist then up to the boxes. Either with a T as you suggest or use one Type FSC box for inline connection. If you need more volume the 1-gang Type FD boxes are 25 cu. in. and 2-gang versions are also available.

If this were a home and not a cabin I might go to the trouble of mounting boxes flush inside the rim joist. But that seems unnecessary here.

[image: Carlon 1-gang 19 cu. in. Type FSE Box]